# What does the Xcode > File > Project Settings actually do?

Tags: xcode, build, project-settings

I recently discovered a handy menu item in Xcode.

There is a menu in Xcode 7.0.1 in `File > Project Settings`. Its content looks like just what I need ie set the Build folder on a per project basis.

It not exactly the same box as in `Xcode > Preferences > Locations`

However, even if Xcode seems to pick up the new location and compile in it, I don't see anything changed in the project pbxproj (using a git diff).

I want to commit them  inside the project and tell the Continuous Integration server to use the same settings as my developement computer.

So my question is: What exactly these settings do (same as the ones found in locations?) and more importantly where are they stored?

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]